# На ubuntu 19.10 не ставиться php7.2-simplexml

Tags: php, ubuntu, composer, laravel-5.6

Обновился до системы **Ubuntu 19.10**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
$ cat /etc/*release*

DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=19.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=eoan
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 19.10"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="19.10 (Eoan Ermine)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 19.10"
VERSION_ID="19.10"
VERSION_CODENAME=eoan
UBUNTU_CODENAME=eoan
```

Пытаюсь запустить проект на `Laravel` и получаю такую ошибку:

> Status Code: 502 Bad Gateway

Думаю, ага такое я уже видел. Делаю:

```
composer install
```

И тут мои ожидания подтвердились:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь: `sudo apt-get remove php7.2-simplexml`, но:

> E: Невозможно найти пакет php7.2-simplexml
>   E: Не удалось найти ни один пакет с помощью шаблона «php7.2-simplexml»
>   E: Не удалось найти ни один пакет с помощью регулярного выражения «php7.2-simplexml»

Ставлю пакеты так `sudo apt-get install php*-simplexml`, но:

> Заметьте, выбирается «php7.3-simplexml» для шаблона «php*-simplexml»
>   Заметьте, выбирается «php-simplexml» для шаблона «php*-simplexml»
>   Заметьте, вместо «php-simplexml» выбирается «php7.3-xml»
>   Заметьте, вместо «php7.3-simplexml» выбирается «php7.3-xml»
>   Следующие НОВЫЕ пакеты будут установлены:
>     php7.3-xml

Версия **PHP**:

```
PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.19.04.1 (cli) (built: Oct 24 2019 11:49:39) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.24-0ubuntu0.19.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

Список зависимостей (`cat /etc/apt/sources.list`):

```html
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 19.04 _Disco Dingo_ - Release amd64 (20190416)]/ disco main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan main restricted
# deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan universe
# deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco universe
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-updates universe
# deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan multiverse
# deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco multiverse
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu disco partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu disco partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security multiverse

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
# deb [arch=amd64] http://mirrors.syringanetworks.net/mariadb/repo/10.4/ubuntu eoan main # заблокировано при обновлении до eoan
# deb-src [arch=amd64] http://mirrors.syringanetworks.net/mariadb/repo/10.4/ubuntu disco main
```

Ситуация не меняется. Как решить проблему?

Comment: а какая версия php в системе?

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Репозиторий дефолтный?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте поставить из другого репозитория

```
apt-get install software-properties-common
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
apt-get install php7.2-simplexml
```

Comment: `add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php` — что это за репозиторий?

Comment: Оказалось, что обновление (обновление `Ubuntu с 19.04 до 19.10`) снесло `php7.2.-fpm`. Полезный ресурс: https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/nginx-502-bad-gateway-errors-php-fpm/#toc-php-fpm-isn-t-running

Comment: репозиторий с разными версиями пхп. дает возможность поставить нужную версию по выбору. встречается во всех солюшенах "как поставить php версии x.y на ubuntu/debian". Раньше также ставили 7 взамен дефолтной 5.6, теперь ситуация сменилась на обратную)))

Comment: Видимо настало время апгрейдить php с выравниванием версий всех компонентов

Comment: Уже) Почему в 19.10 отказались от php7.2)

Comment: Ибо уже грядет 7.4

Answer (score 3):

Как можно заметить по:

> 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.**19.04**.1

Сейчас у вас система представляет собой франкенштейна с частично заменёнными фрагментами тела. Пакет за этим идентификатором версии [сейчас отслеживается](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/php7.2) как актуальное исправление безопасности в ubuntu 19.04.

В репозиториях ubuntu 19.10 пакетов php для ветки 7.2.х просто нет. Там поставляется 7.3.

Поэтому если вам нужен именно 7.2 - то вам нужны какие-то сторонние репозитории. Возможно можно взять из репозитория ubuntu 19.04

---

Либо обновляться полноценно до PHP 7.3. Для этого необходимо выяснить, какие пакеты у вас стоят, почему на php-cli отзывается 7.2 и как вызывать 7.3.

Comment: +1 к ответу. Спасибо.